# sed is causing my computer to hang

Tags: shell, sed, awk

I have this nifty little script that does a nice job of manipulating some data files for me...first it strips out unwanted data after the first semicolon, then it changes the data into a Unicode string, then removes any newline chars, and finally shuffles it into two mixed files (a and b) that I need to use.

It works beautifully with small files, but I'm now dealing with a file that's so large that sed is hanging.  Or perhaps that's what's happening...I don't know exactly.  Is there anyone out there who can offer a suggestion on how to (maybe?) buffer this or prevent it from hanging?  (I've got 16GB ram and the file is...1707772 (k?  I'm "ls -la"ing)...is that too large?)  I'm seeing 100%cpu usage that's never going away...only killing the process returns the window to usable.

Here's the code:

```
#!/bin/bash
a="a";
b="b";
echo "Input Filename:";
read ifilename;
echo "Output Filename:";
read ofilename;
awk '{
    #dbg print "$0=" $0
    sub(/;.*$/, "")
    len=length($0)
    if (len == 4) {print "&#x0" $0 ";"}
    else if (len == 5) {print "&#x" $0 ";"}
    else {print "error in input: found len=" len " in XX" $0 "xx"}
}' /home/myhome/$ifilename > temp.txt;
cat temp.txt | tr -d "\n" > temp_nolfs.txt;
cat temp_nolfs.txt | sed -r 's/(.[^;]*;)/ \1 /g' | tr " " "\n" | shuf | tr -d "\n" > $ofilename$a".txt";
cat temp_nolfs.txt | sed -r 's/(.[^;]*;)/ \1 /g' | tr " " "\n" | shuf | tr -d "\n" > $ofilename$b".txt";
rm temp.txt;
rm temp_nolfs.txt;
echo "Done!";
```

Thanks for any and all suggestions!

Comment: Tip: Instead of ls -al, use ls -lah, h for human readable. Can you spot on which line it hangs?

Comment: As has been said above, I suggest putting in some echo statements, to see where it hangs. Can you try the awk command standalone?

Comment: I'd really be surprised if sed has stopped altogether, especially with CPU at 100%. Run it overnight and it will probably finish. Depending on what you're trying to parse out in your sed command, sometimes a change like `s/^(.[^;]*;)/ \1 /g` can make a huge difference in runtime. Good luck.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Many thanks for the helpful suggestions; however, the issue wasn't sed at all...I had been feeding it data with NO semicolon, which meant it was looking forever for something that didn't exist.  Worked fine, redundancies nonwithstanding, once I fed it properly structured data.

Answer (score 2):

Your script needs serious refactoring. It has many redundant command using pipes that can be easily reduced eg:

- `cat temp_nolfs.txt | sed ...` can easily become `sed temp_nolfs.txt ...`
- All the calls of `tr` can be handled in awk and/or sed
- sed -i can be utilized to eliminate creation of temporary files
- etc etc.

Once that is done I'm sure script will become more efficient to handle large files.

Comment: Agreed. If the OP shows sample input and desired output, the OP may find several far more efficient solutions offered.